# Using Retorift 2.0 Exception

Tags: android, retrofit

i'm trying to use retorift 2.0 library to handle my network operations in my android application 
i've followed the sample in the github but t returned null
i've done my own code also returned json must strt with an objcet or an array
below is my code sample

```
    public void createUser(String email, String password, String device_tocken, String device_type, String availability, String user_name) {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    ICreate iCreate = retrofit.create(ICreate.class);
    try {
        Call<RegistrationResult> call = iCreate.create(email, password, device_tocken, device_type, availability, user_name);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<RegistrationResult> response) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context,t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        retrofit.Response<RegistrationResult> r =call.execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

and here is my response result

```
  public class RegistrationResult {
    public final String status;


    public RegistrationResult(String status) {

        this.status = status;

    }
}
```

could you help me ...
thanks

Comment: What does the JSON you are getting look like?

Comment: there is no JSON in your question.... try this tutorial http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-retrofit-tutorial/

Comment: iam asking about retrofit v 2.0 this tutorial is 1.9 thanks